# What are the reported effects of a pilgrimage to Saint James of Compostela?

Tags: catholicism, christian-living

In Catholic traditions, pilgrimages are sometimes undertaken with a view that specific effects may adhere to the pilgrim.  For [St. James of Compostela](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Way_of_St._James), are there specific traditions about what a pilgrimage to this site in particular can expect to happen that would be different from other pilgrimages?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This next is just standard to help new visitors avoid misunderstanding the site (as I did at first.)  As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [the help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)

Comment: @DJClayworth & David Stratton Sure, I've read the pages, thank you ;) Though I'm pretty sure that "Affable Geek" has made a good job of editing the question. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Yes, great job. And again, welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though not as holy as Rome or Jerusalem, the Cathedral of Santiago, believed to be the resting place of St. James, did confer special status.

Specifically:

- [Pilgrims who completed the journey](http://www.csj.org.uk/compostela.htm) in a Jubilee Year were often given a [plenary indulgence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indulgence), forgiving them of the (earthly) consequences of a crime.

Additionally:

> - There is still a tradition in Flanders of pardoning and releasing one prisoner every year under the condition that this prisoner walks to Santiago wearing a heavy backpack, accompanied by a guard. (from Wikipedia)